# Dependency on .aar cannot be resolved in higher level modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libraries, aar

I'm using a certain SDK that comes in a couple of .aar files. Their instructions for importing it in my project are, in short:

- put the .aar files in a "libs" folder inside your module
- add to the build.gradle (for each of the aar files):

  ```
  compile(name: 'xxx-release', ext: 'aar')
  ```
- add to the build.gradle:

  ```
  repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
    }
  }
  ```
- clean project, sync gradle

This works in a simple project, but not in mine. My project is build from multiple modules:

```
  project
    mainModule1
    mainModule2
    mainModule3
    sharedModule1
      libs/xxx-release.aar
      libs/x.aar
    sharedModuleX
```

I have three main modules that are used for different variants of the app. These three modules depend on a number of other modules. Those (sub) modules are shared between the main ones and contain various app features. We put a lot of effort in making the app as modularized as possibe. Inside one of these shared (sub) modules there is a libs folder where I have added the aar files. The build.gradle of that module (sharedModule1) contains the "dependencies" and "repositories" blocks.

Only that module will ever use those aar dependencies, so I prefer to keep them inside the module. Furthermore, the vendor of the aar's SDK recommends the same.

The sharedModule1's dependencies work, Gradle does not complain about it.
However, I get errors on the main modules. Apparently they also depend on the aars but the dependencies cannot be resolved.

The errors look like, for each main module:

```
    .../MainModule1/build.gradle
    Failed to resolve: :xxx-release
    Failed to resolve: :etc-release
```

How do I get those dependencies to work? The aars should be available both in their sub-module, and in the main modules.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: I tried with 2.1, now I am using 2.2 on the Canary channel. Gradle - gradle-2.13-all; com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0

Comment: Same issue here, did you manage to solve it? I have AAR included in my library module, then when I sync everything at App level it can't find the AAR file.

Comment: I got it to work, in the end, but I don't remember the details. One thing is for certain - we decided to put the AARs in Artifactory and add a Maven dependency for them, this way avoiding committing them to the repository. I think that this helped with the problem. Sorry, it was a long time ago...